# Power BI: modify slicer input to filter different values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

Please help me if you know how to solve this:

I have a column which I imported using a direct query that has date and time values in a single column with each field looking like this:

2018-07-10 4:01:36 PM

I want to use these values to let the user choose the date using a slicer with the date as input. For example, if the user selects 2019-01-01, I want to select all rows which have a date-time value between 2019-01-01 4:00:00 AM and 2019-01-02 4:00:00 AM.

Another example: If I select 2020-01-27 - it should include results when 2020-01-27 4:00:00 AM <= DTM < 2020-01-28 4:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

You can create a modified date field and use that as the filter instead:

```
Modified Date = IF(HOUR(Table1[Date])<4,Table1[Date],Table1[Date]-1)
```

Now you can use this calculated column in the slicer and it should give the desired output. Hope this helps.